# Can i implement select statement after I create a trigger in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I want to select new students who are just inserted into the table and I want to create a trigger for this.

```
create trigger R1
after insert on Student
for each row
when New.GPA > 3.5
begin 
select New.studentID from Student
end;
```

Student is a table. Can I do something like this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to do? Select the ID and then what?

Comment: You don't `select` in triggers.  You are misunderstanding some important concept.

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve, then community may offer the best solution. As @Gordon Linoff said selecting from a trigger is a very bad idea.

Comment: @atm  Thank you! I want to create a table containing students whose GPA are greater than 3.5 (student id, student name, status). However, the Student table get updated every day so I want to update my table to add new students whose GPA are greater than 3.5 and for students whose GPA are updated to be below 3.5, add "delete" in status table (since the student table changed all the time, their GPA also changed along the time).

Comment: @April . . . In a real application it is probably better to do those calculations on the fly when you query the table.